# Should Sentry with AngularJS detect errors in Ajax calls?

Tags: angularjs, sentry

I'm evaluating [Sentry.io](https://Sentry.io) for use with an AngularJS (1.x) application (See [Sentry docs for AngularJS](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/angular/#angularjs-1x)).

The docs say that Sentry integrates with frameworks seamlessly: See
https://docs.sentry.io/error-reporting/capturing/?platform=javascript#capturing-messages

So... I tried forcing an error in both an AngularJS form and inside an $http.get().then() AJAX handler.

`throw new Error('Somethings wrong')`

But the error was not automatically sent to Sentry.  If I changed the error to

`Sentry.captureException('Somethings wrong');`

then the error does show up in Sentry, so I know that Sentry is available in this code.

My question is: **How can I get Sentry to automatically instrument all of my AngularJS 1.x code so any error exception is automatically sent to Sentry?**

I'm hoping to have any exceptions from rending forms (AngularJS *.html) or `$http.get` to be automatically handled.

## Searching for solutions

I searched for solutions using google `Sentry AngularJS` and got several potential hits, but most were not useful.  The useful ones are shown below:

- [Sentry Install/Setup docs](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/angular/#angularjs-1x) - Explains how to integrate Sentry with an AngularJS 1.x application.
- [Sending AngularJS Errors To New Relic, Raygun, Sentry, etc](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2859-sending-angularjs-errors-to-new-relic-raygun-sentry-etc.htm)
- [Handling login events with Sentry and AngularJS](https://robbiemackay.com/learned/2017/03/20/handling-login-with-sentry-and-angular)

But nothing (yet) on StackOverflow, so I figured I'd ask the question since this is my GO TO place to find answers.

Comment: Why don't you ask Sentry?  Links: https://sentry.io/contact/support/, https://forum.sentry.io/

Comment: OK, I added it at https://forum.sentry.io/t/angularjs-http-get/8490

Comment: You can take a look at XHR interceptors that will process the response before it reaches then() or catch() blocks and sendException() from there. I have only done it with axios, but I assume the same can be applied to your code

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to include `ngSentry` as a dependency:

> ```
> // Finally require ngSentry as a dependency in your application module.
> angular.module('yourApplicationModule', ['ngSentry']);
> ```